# How would I go about creating a boolean matrix from a 2D game image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Here presented is a screenshot from a 2D game:

[(Sorry, don't have the reputation to post inline images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvWEz.jpg)

You can walk on the grass, the asphalt, sidewalk etc. but you cannot walk into buildings/walls/any structures. Here is a [small gif](https://i.imgur.com/1RL0o9A.gif) to demonstrate this

*What I want:* my ideal goal is to create a boolean matrix, where 0 means you can't traverse through that pixel and 1 means you can. So, in this example, it would look something like [this (I forgot to add the trees)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzqDX.jpg)

Where the "red zones" would be 0 in this array and the other tiles would be 1

What I've tried and what I had in mind:

All of my ideas lead to one thing, and I don't know if it's right: creating one universal list of "accepted" colors where we could set the pixel to be set to 1 if it's in that list of acceptable colors. This of course has its downsides: one of them being that a non-traversable territory could easily have a color of a traversable one (for example if we're using green as in the color of grass - that could be swamp or bushes), and the other downside is computation time to compare each pixel.

I've considered *thresholds* but if I got it correctly, it's only used for white and black comparisons.
I've also looked at *image quantization* using PIL, but the quantized image didn't change much for me. What would I do after the quantization?

If we look deeper into this game, a *tile* here is considered a 32x32 pixel area and it's drawn using a *tileset* (sort of a canvas): https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xmi.png and there is a list of "non-traversable" tiles (blocking), maybe it's somehow possible to use it?

Anyways, I'm lost at what to look for. I've been researching but found nothing similar. I would appreciate any advice on where to look, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps filter your image by color and use edge detection on what remains, where edges define regions of 1s in your matrix. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-edge-detection-using-pillow/

Comment: You're asking for open-ended help in system design; this is somewhat out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Of course, you can extract all tiles, get lists of blocking and non-blocking tiles, and simply use template matching. Actually, I'm quite sure, you'll get perfect results using that method - because it's the way, how the map is created, and how traversability is determined in-game. Nevertheless, iterating such a huge list of templates, this approach won't be very efficient, I'm afraid.